# How to get the position of 2D dicom image slice in 3D surface rendered output in vtk

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

I am doing a VTK program in that when I enter a **2D DICOM patient image position** (kindly refer the given image for better understanding), **I need to get that particular slice in the 3D surface rendered output.**

For volume rendered 3D image this can be achieved by using these functions namely vtkImageData, vtkImageMapToColors,vtkImage Actor.

[image]
My question is how to do it in the surface rendered output.do anyone know the concept for that. If anybody knows please answer. If my question is incorrect or not understandable kindly share your opinion.

For clear understanding I am showing a sample picture

consider my 3d output will be like the picture below

[image]

and **when I enter the image position(patient) in a text box and click ok button that corresponding slice should be shown in the 3d image like the below picture**

[image]

please inform if my question is not understandable
I got stuck here i don't even know whether my code is right.Here is my code

```
    ExtractVOI->SetInput(reader1->GetOutput());//VOI extractor
    ExtractVOI->SetVOI(1,0,0,0,1,0);//i have given the Image Orientation(patient) as the SetVOI value


    ////====CREATE LookUpTable

    tableax1->SetTableRange(0.0, 4096.0);
    tableax1->SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0); 
    tableax1->SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0); 
    tableax1->SetRampToSCurve();
    tableax1->SetAlphaRange(0.0, 0.08);
    tableax1->Build();      

    //====CREATE TEXTURE

    planesourceax1->SetXResolution(1);
    planesourceax1->SetYResolution(1);
    planesourceax1->SetOrigin(0,0,0);
    planesourceax1->SetPoint1(xg , yg,zg);//i have given the value of Image Position(patient) that is taken from a textbox ,as the points

    planesourceax1->Update();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapax1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapax1->SetInputConnection(planesourceax1->GetOutputPort());

    mapax1->UpdateWholeExtent();
    textureax1->SetInputConnection(ExtractVOI->GetOutputPort());
    textureax1->InterpolateOn();
    textureax1->SetLookupTable(tableax1);
    textureax1->UpdateWholeExtent();

    //===PASS TO ACTOR
    actorax1->SetMapper(mapax1);
    actorax1->GetMapper()->SetResolveCoincidentTopologyToPolygonOffset();
    actorax1->GetMapper()->SetResolveCoincidentTopologyPolygonOffsetParameters(0.1, -1.0);
    actorax1->SetTexture(textureax1);


    renderer->AddActor(actorax1);

    renderWindow->Render();
```

but i am not getting output

*I also tried:*

```
static double axialElements[16] = {
                                                                        1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                                        0, 1, 0, 0,
                                                                        0, 0, 1, 0,
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 1  };

        resliceax1->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
        resliceax1->SetOutputDimensionality(2);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> reslicematrixax1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
        reslicematrixax1->DeepCopy(axialElements);
        resliceax1->SetResliceAxes(reslicematrixax1);
        resliceax1->SetResliceAxesOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        resliceax1->Update();

        extractaxpos1->RemoveAllInputs();
        extractaxpos1->SetInputConnection(resliceax1->GetOutputPort());


        ////====CREATE LUT

        tableax1->SetTableRange(0.0, 4096.0);
        tableax1->SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0); 
        tableax1->SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0); 
        tableax1->SetRampToSCurve();
        tableax1->SetAlphaRange(0.0, 0.08);
        tableax1->Build();      

        //====CREATE TEXTURE

        planesourceax1->SetXResolution(1);
        planesourceax1->SetYResolution(1);
        planesourceax1->SetOrigin(0,0,0);
        planesourceax1->SetPoint1((xval/20 + xval/32),(yval/20 + yval/32),(zval/20 + zval/32));//this is where i put the values ad divided by its tag id(0020,0032)
        //planesourceax1->SetPoint2(fBounds[0] , fBounds[3], fBounds[4]);
        planesourceax1->Update();
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapax1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
        mapax1->SetInputConnection(planesourceax1->GetOutputPort());

        mapax1->UpdateWholeExtent();
        textureax1->SetInputConnection(extractaxpos1->GetOutputPort());
        textureax1->InterpolateOn();
        textureax1->SetLookupTable(tableax1);
        textureax1->UpdateWholeExtent();

        //===PASS TO ACTOR
        actorax1->SetMapper(mapax1);
        actorax1->GetMapper()->SetResolveCoincidentTopologyToPolygonOffset();
        actorax1->GetMapper()->SetResolveCoincidentTopologyPolygonOffsetParameters(0.1, -1.0);
        actorax1->SetTexture(textureax1);

        resliceax1->SetResliceAxesOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        actorax1->SetPosition((xval/20 + xval/32),(yval/20 + yval/32),(zval/20 + zval/32));//I made the same changes here also

        planesourceax1->SetOrigin(fBoundsUpdated[0], fBoundsUpdated[2], pDoc->fBounds[4]);
        planesourceax1->SetPoint1(fBoundsUpdated[1] , fBoundsUpdated[2], pDoc->fBounds[4]);
        planesourceax1->SetPoint2(fBoundsUpdated[0] , fBoundsUpdated[3], pDoc->fBounds[4]);
        planesourceax1->Update();
```

**but it is not cutting the position where the slice is.It is cutting a different position**

Comment: You have a flat 2D image, I did not understand on what surface you want to show it. You just want it on a 3D plane?

Comment: Ok now it is clear what you want to do. Where do you get stuck? I suggest you post your current code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is there any vtk type which can obtain image position (patient) and image orientation( patient).I tried using vtkImageActor->SetPosition(//patient image position values//) but not working

Comment: If you want to create a plane with texture, simply use 0020|0032 for the origin, 0020|0037 for directions along image axes and 0028|0030 and image size to compute the extent of the plane. Bear in mind, DICOM origin is center of pixel unlike OpenGL origin being the corner. So you want to shift OpenGL origin by -0.5 spacing. Better do a simple quad vtkPolyData using InsertNextCell, InsertNextPoint and .. Tuple functions for cells, points and tcoords.

Comment: can u explain with code?@mainactual

Comment: can i use other dicom tags such as "slice location"or "image orientation"or" pixel spacing"etc to find the dicom slice in 3d output?@mainactual

Comment: @Ria it's quite a lot of code to make it a runnable code snippet. VTK does not fully support image orientation ( https://discourse.vtk.org/t/proposal-to-add-orientation-to-vtkimagedata-feedback-wanted/120/1 ), which makes it somewhat easier and always restricted to cartesian axes. Are you happy with z-slicing only as are the DICOM frames?

Comment: yes sir.now i just want to show where the particular dicom image slice is located in the 3d output using any methods @ mainactual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a DICOM slice, position goes directly into the `SetResliceAxesOrigin`, whereas texture primitive is shifted a bit to make the VTK center of pixel -units to correspond with OpenGL bounds. Then the image dimensions and spacing along X and Y axis are used to calculate the extent of the primitive (track the prints of DICOM tags). Directions can be currently omitted since `vtkImageData` doesn't have them (https://discourse.vtk.org/t/proposal-to-add-orientation-to-vtkimagedata-feedback-wanted/120/2). But they are most likely (hopefully) baked into the image data during reading.

You can verify the rendering by comparing with volume or surface models.

For handling medical image data, I recommend ITK (https://itk.org/). If still not using ITK, just read the image and call the output as `image` in the code.

Sample print:

```
0020|0037 1\-2.58172e-10\3.63164e-11\-1.26711e-11\-0.187259\-0.982311
Warning, direction will be lost
0018|0050 1
0028|0030 1\1
0020|0032 -252.69\-118.273\305.807
```

[image]

```
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageFileReader.h"

#include "vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h"
#include "vtkImplicitPlaneWidget2.h"
#include "vtkImplicitPlaneRepresentation.h"
#include "vtkCommand.h"
#include "vtkPlane.h"
#include "vtkImageMapToColors.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkPolyData.h"
#include "vtkPoints.h"
#include "vtkCellArray.h"
#include "vtkFloatArray.h"
#include "vtkImageReslice.h"
#include "vtkPiecewiseFunction.h"
#include "vtkColorTransferFunction.h"
#include "vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.h"
#include "vtkVolumeProperty.h"
#include "vtkTexture.h"
#include "vtkLookupTable.h"
#include "vtkImageMarchingCubes.h"

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> MyCreateSimplePlane( const double * corners )
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>  ret=vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkFloatArray > tcoords = vtkSmartPointer< vtkFloatArray >::New();
    tcoords->SetNumberOfComponents( 2 );
    tcoords->InsertNextTuple2( 0, 0 );
    tcoords->InsertNextTuple2( 1, 0 );
    tcoords->InsertNextTuple2( 1, 1 );
    tcoords->InsertNextTuple2( 0, 1 );
    ret->GetPointData()->SetTCoords( tcoords );

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> floatArray = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
    floatArray->SetNumberOfComponents( 3 );
    for ( int i=0;i<4;++i )
    {
        floatArray->InsertNextTuple3( corners[3*i], corners[3*i+1], corners[3*i+2] );
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    points->SetData( floatArray );
    ret->SetPoints( points );   

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> cells = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
    cells->InsertNextCell( 4 );
    cells->InsertCellPoint( 0 );
    cells->InsertCellPoint( 1 );
    cells->InsertCellPoint( 2 );
    cells->InsertCellPoint( 3 );
    ret->SetPolys( cells );
    return ret;
}
void mainactual( void )
{
    bool doVolumeRender = true;
    bool doSurfaceRender = false;

    typedef itk::Image<short,3> Image;
    typedef itk::VTKImageExport< Image > Export;
    typedef itk::ImageFileReader<Image> Reader;

    // read image using ITK (this is essentially an nrrd-converted Visible Human CT "Male")
    // https://mri.radiology.uiowa.edu/VHDicom/

    // prefer using ITK for medical data
    Reader::Pointer reader = Reader::New();
    reader->SetFileName("D:/tmp/vhp_male.nrrd");
    reader->Update();

    // if input image orientation is not (1,0,0\0,1,0), user should handle
    // the respective transform by using, e.g., vtkVolume::SetOrientation
    Image::DirectionType dir = reader->GetOutput()->GetDirection();

    std::cout << "0020|0037" << " ";
    std::cout << dir(0,0) << "\\" << dir(1,0) << "\\" << dir(2,0) << "\\";
    std::cout << dir(0,1) << "\\" << dir(1,1) << "\\" << dir(2,1);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( !dir.GetVnlMatrix().is_identity( 0.0001 ) )
        std::cout << "Warning, direction will be lost" << std::endl;

    // import ITK image into VTK
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> imp = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport>::New();
    Export::Pointer exp = Export::New();

    exp->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() );
    imp->SetUpdateInformationCallback(exp->GetUpdateInformationCallback());
    imp->SetPipelineModifiedCallback(exp->GetPipelineModifiedCallback());
    imp->SetWholeExtentCallback(exp->GetWholeExtentCallback());
    imp->SetSpacingCallback(exp->GetSpacingCallback());
    imp->SetOriginCallback(exp->GetOriginCallback());
    imp->SetScalarTypeCallback(exp->GetScalarTypeCallback());
    imp->SetNumberOfComponentsCallback(exp->GetNumberOfComponentsCallback());
    imp->SetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback(exp->GetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback());
    imp->SetUpdateDataCallback(exp->GetUpdateDataCallback());
    imp->SetDataExtentCallback(exp->GetDataExtentCallback());
    imp->SetBufferPointerCallback(exp->GetBufferPointerCallback());
    imp->SetCallbackUserData(exp->GetCallbackUserData());
    imp->Update();

    // this is our vtkImageData counterpart as it was read using VTK
    vtkImageData * image = imp->GetOutput();

    // create render window
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderer > ren = vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderer >::New();
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindow > rw = vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindow >::New();
    rw->AddRenderer( ren );
    rw->SetSize( 1024,1024 );
    // create interactor used later
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindowInteractor > ia = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    ia->SetRenderWindow( rw );
    ia->SetInteractorStyle(  vtkSmartPointer< vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera >::New() );
    ia->Initialize();

    // define cutplane early on
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane > cutplane = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
    cutplane->SetNormal( 0,0,-1);

    if ( doVolumeRender )
    {
        // set up some fancy volume rendering transfer function
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> pw = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();
        pw->AddPoint(-761.61130742049477, 0);
        pw->AddPoint(-40.042402826855096, 0);
        pw->AddPoint(353.54063604240287, 0.28817733990147787);
        pw->AddPoint(1091.5088339222616, 0.69458128078817727);
        pw->AddPoint(1763.8798586572439, 1);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> gf = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();
        gf->AddPoint(-1024, 0);
        gf->AddPoint(-1007.6007067137809, 1);
        gf->AddPoint(-220.43462897526501, 0.78244274809160308);
        gf->AddPoint(697.92579505300364, 0.9007633587786259);
        gf->AddPoint(1157.1060070671379, 0.53435114503816794);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> cf = vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();
        cf->AddRGBPoint(-105.63957597173146, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0);
        cf->AddRGBPoint(255.14487632508826, 0.93333299999999997, 0, 0, 0.5, 0);
        cf->AddRGBPoint(353.54063604240287, 1, 0.90588199999999997, 0.66666700000000001, 0.5, 0);
        cf->AddRGBPoint(632.32862190812716, 1, 0.66666666666666663, 0, 0.5, 0);
        cf->AddRGBPoint(779.92226148409895, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0);

        // and make GPUVolumeRayCastMapper to render them
        typedef vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper Mapper;
        vtkSmartPointer< Mapper > mapper = vtkSmartPointer< Mapper >::New();
        mapper->SetInputData( image );  
        vtkSmartPointer< vtkVolumeProperty > prop = vtkSmartPointer< vtkVolumeProperty >::New();
        prop->SetColor( cf );
        prop->SetScalarOpacity( pw );
        prop->SetGradientOpacity( gf );
        prop->SetInterpolationTypeToLinear();
        prop->SetDiffuse( 0 );
        prop->SetSpecular( 0.0 );
        prop->SetAmbient( 1 );
        mapper->SetUseDepthPass( 1 );
        mapper->SetUseJittering( 1 );
        mapper->SetAutoAdjustSampleDistances( 0 );
        vtkSmartPointer< vtkVolume > volume = vtkSmartPointer< vtkVolume >::New();
        volume->SetMapper( mapper );
        volume->SetProperty( prop );

        // clip the volume
        mapper->AddClippingPlane( cutplane );
        ren->AddVolume( volume );
    }

    if ( doSurfaceRender )
    {
        // do marching cubes polygons
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMarchingCubes> mc = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMarchingCubes>::New();
        mc->SetComputeGradients( 0 );
        mc->SetComputeNormals( 0 );
        mc->SetComputeScalars( 0 );
        mc->SetInputData( image );
        mc->SetNumberOfContours( 1 );
        mc->SetValue( 0, 100.0 );
        mc->Update();

        vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper > surfmapper = vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper >::New();
        vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor > surf = vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor >::New();
        surf->SetMapper( surfmapper );
        surfmapper->SetInputData( mc->GetOutput() );
        surf->GetProperty()->SetAmbient(0);
        surf->GetProperty()->SetDiffuse(1);
        surf->GetProperty()->SetSpecular(0);
        surf->GetProperty()->SetColor( 0.5, 0.9, 0.1 );

        surfmapper->AddClippingPlane( cutplane );
        ren->AddActor( surf );
    }

    // do the image slice plane
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkImageReslice > slicer = vtkSmartPointer< vtkImageReslice >::New();
    slicer->SetInputData( image );
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> identity = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New() ;
    //identity->Identity(); // not needed as the orientation is identity anyways
    slicer->SetResliceAxes( identity );
    slicer->SetOutputDimensionality( 2 );
    slicer->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();

    vtkSmartPointer< vtkTexture > texture = vtkSmartPointer< vtkTexture > ::New();
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkLookupTable > table = vtkSmartPointer< vtkLookupTable >::New();

    table->SetNumberOfColors( 256 );
    table->SetHueRange( 0.0, 0.0 );
    table->SetSaturationRange( 0, 0 );
    table->SetValueRange( 0.0, 1.0 );
    table->SetAlphaRange( 1.0, 1.0 );
    table->SetUseBelowRangeColor( 1 );
    table->SetBelowRangeColor(0,0,0,0);
    table->SetRange( -200, 200 );
    table->Build();

    texture->SetInputConnection( slicer->GetOutputPort() );
    texture->SetLookupTable( table );
    texture->SetColorModeToMapScalars();

    vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper > polymapper = vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper >::New();
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor > plane = vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor >::New();
    plane->SetMapper( polymapper );
    plane->GetProperty()->SetTexture(0, texture );
    plane->GetProperty()->SetAmbient(1);
    plane->GetProperty()->SetDiffuse(0);
    plane->GetProperty()->SetSpecular(0);
    plane->GetProperty()->SetAmbientColor(1,1,1);
    plane->GetProperty()->SetEdgeColor(1,0,0);
    plane->GetProperty()->SetEdgeVisibility(1);
    ren->AddActor( plane );

    int extent[6];
    double origin[3];
    double spacing[3];
    image->GetOrigin( origin );
    image->GetSpacing( spacing );
    image->GetExtent( extent );

    {
        std::stringstream s;
        std::cout << "0018|0050" << " ";
        std::cout << spacing[2];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::cout << "0028|0030" << " ";
        std::cout << spacing[0] << "\\" << spacing[1];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    ren->ResetCamera(); // before looping, hope there is either surface or volume

    int z = (extent[5]-extent[4])/2;
    // for ( ... )
    {
        // DICOM pixel corner
        double corner[3]={ origin[0], origin[1], origin[2] + (double)z * spacing[2] };
        std::cout << "0020|0032" << " ";
        std::cout << corner[0] << "\\" << corner[1] << "\\" << corner[2];
        std::cout << std::endl;


        slicer->SetResliceAxesOrigin( corner );
        double corners[12];

        // remove the half spacing to make DICOM / ITK / VTK origin to OpenGL origin
        corners[0]=corner[0]-0.5*spacing[0];
        corners[1]=corner[1]-0.5*spacing[1];
        corners[2]=corner[2]; // the slicing direction
        // +1 are to convert from DICOM pixel coordinates to OpenGL bounds
        const double vx[3]={ (double)(extent[1]-extent[0]+1)*spacing[0], 0.0, 0.0 }; 
        const double vy[3]={ 0.0, (double)(extent[3]-extent[2]+1)*spacing[1], 0.0} ; 



        for ( unsigned int u=0;u<3;++u )
        {
            corners[ 3+ u ] = corners[u] + vx[u];
            corners[ 6+ u ] = corners[u] + vx[u] + vy[u];
            corners[ 9+ u ] = corners[u] + vy[u];
        }
        cutplane->SetOrigin( corner );

        vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyData > polys = MyCreateSimplePlane( corners );
        polymapper->SetInputData( polys );
        ia->Render();
    }
    ia->Start();
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
Note: the direction must be processed separately, e.g., via `SetUserTransform` for both the plane and the volume, or resampling of the imagedata. Two images shown below are sliced similarly along the outermost image dimension, and not along the worldspace z-axis:

[image]

Comment: thanks sir.I just have a doubt , will this code displays whether the dicom image is obliged ((eg.)suppose it is an MRI image with orientation(0.707,0.707,0,0.707,0.707,0)?

Comment: @Ria you can use this code to render slices (image grid z-direction) of any image stack, as the orientation is cut at `itk::Image` to `vtkImageData` step and thus the image will appear as it was oriented along the right-hand side Cartesian axes anyway. In reality, you probably want to calculate the transform from orientation to Cartesian, which you can then apply to both the plane and the volume.

Comment: you mean yes or no sir :-)?

Comment: @Ria best explained by image, see below (answer is yes for the image dimension, no for the worldspace z-dimension)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what element decide cutting direction

https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/ImageProcessing/Cxx/ImageSlicing.cxx

please look this link

```
static double axialElements[16] = {
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1 };
```

...

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> resliceAxes = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
resliceAxes->DeepCopy(axialElements);
// Set the point through which to slice
resliceAxes->SetElement(0, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(1, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(2, 3, 70);
```

Matrix 4x4  is setting **Reslice direction** 
and SetElement decide **Reslice origin**

this code setting option is Reslice XYimage start at Z = 70

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> reslice = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
    reslice->SetInputData(m_vtkVolumeImageData);
    reslice->SetOutputDimensionality(2);
    reslice->SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes);
    reslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();
    reslice->Update();
```

this code make Reslice Data. 
Result Dimesionality is made 2D(Plane)
and if you setting this sequence, 
connect Reslice data to vtkImageMapToColors for paint Reslice image.

and last, Connect Mapper and Actor for show with Volume.
you need to setting Actor location because Reslice Data maybe dosen't have a location info

if Plane location is not changed, using vtkDataSetMapper and vtkActor, not vtkImageActor

Or you just use Widget,
I recommand vtkImagePlaneWidget.

It is easy and very Powerful.

I hope it will help you.

If you need full code, please tell me

Answer (score -1):

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::setSliceImage()
{
int extent[6];
double spacing[3];
double origin[3];

//m_vtkVolumeImageData is vtkImageData(Save Slice Images)
//Same as dicomReader->GetOutput();
m_vtkVolumeImageData->GetExtent(extent);
m_vtkVolumeImageData->GetSpacing(spacing);
m_vtkVolumeImageData->GetOrigin(origin);

double center[3];
center[0] = origin[0] + spacing[0] * 0.5 * (extent[0] + extent[1]);
center[1] = origin[1] + spacing[1] * 0.5 * (extent[2] + extent[3]);
center[2] = origin[2] + spacing[2] * 0.5 * (extent[4] + extent[5]);

// Matrices for axial, coronal, sagittal, oblique view orientations
static double axialElements[16] = {
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1 };

static double coronalElements[16] = {
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0,-1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1 };

static double sagittalElements[16] = {
         0, 0,-1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0,-1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1 };

static double obliqueElements[16] = {
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0.866025, -0.5, 0,
         0, 0.5, 0.866025, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1 };

// Set the slice orientation
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> resliceAxes = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
resliceAxes->DeepCopy(axialElements);
// Set the point through which to slice
resliceAxes->SetElement(0, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(1, 3, 0);
resliceAxes->SetElement(2, 3, 70);



// Extract a slice in the desired orientation
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> reslice = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
reslice->SetInputData(m_vtkVolumeImageData);
reslice->SetOutputDimensionality(2);
reslice->SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes);
reslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();
reslice->Update();

// Create a lookup table
table = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();

// image intensity range
// my image is USHORT TYPE, so I Set 0 ~ 65535
table->SetRange(0, 65535); 
table->SetNumberOfTableValues(65536);

double red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < table->GetNumberOfTableValues(); i++)
{
    // 0~19999 value have Black ~ Red
    if (i < 20000)
        red += 1.0 / 20000;
    // 20000~39999 value have Red ~ Yellow
    else if (i < 40000)
        green += 1.0 / 20000;
    // 40000~59999 value have Yellow ~ white 
    // and 60000~ have white
    else if (i < 60000)
        blue += 1.0 / 20000;

    table->SetTableValue(i, red, green, blue, 1);
}

table->Build();


//// Map the image through the lookup table
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors> color = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors>::New();
color->SetLookupTable(table);
color->SetInputData(reslice->GetOutput());
color->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputData(color->GetOutput());

//Setting ResliceImagePlaneActor
//Location, Opacity, Connect Mapper and Actor
double position[3] = { 0, 0, 70 };
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> nomal_actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
nomal_actor->SetMapper(mapper);
nomal_actor->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(0.7);
nomal_actor->SetPosition(position);
m_vtkRenderer->AddActor(nomal_actor);


//Setting ReslicePlaneOutLineActor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter> sliceOutlineFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter>::New();
sliceOutlineFilter->SetInputData(color->GetOutput());
sliceOutlineFilter->Update();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> sliceOutlineMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
sliceOutlineMapper->SetInputData(sliceOutlineFilter->GetOutput());
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> vtksliceOutlineActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
vtksliceOutlineActor->SetMapper(sliceOutlineMapper);
vtksliceOutlineActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1, 0, 0);
vtksliceOutlineActor->SetPosition(position);
m_vtkRenderer->AddActor(vtksliceOutlineActor);


//Setting ScalarBarActor
//It is fine to Skip
vtkSmartPointer<vtkScalarBarActor> scalarBar = vtkSmartPointer<vtkScalarBarActor>::New();
scalarBar->SetLookupTable(table);
scalarBar->SetTitle("value");
scalarBar->SetNumberOfLabels(10);
scalarBar->SetLabelFormat("%10.2f");
scalarBar->SetHeight(.2);
scalarBar->SetWidth(.2);


m_vtkRenderer->AddActor2D(scalarBar);
}
```

This is My fullCode

Check it and if you don't understand some parts, Post a comment plz :)

Comment: shall i want to put it in `double position[3]`

Comment: thank you for your answer .But my plane is not in the exact position.

Comment: Where is plane location? Can i see screenshot? and also code too

Comment: for code ; i just changed the position[3] as `double position[3] = {xval,yval,zval }//x,y,z values of the image position (patient) tag` i wrote the remaining code same as your answer.

Comment: well... sry i can't find that err. could you check x, y, z value and see any typo in code? On my experience, value type error was made by mistyping one function previously.

Comment: sir i am just curious to know about  how those elements in the 4*4 matrix are calculated?@ Hyun-jin Won

Comment: I can't explain it clear. That is 3D grapics question, and I don't learn it yet
This link maybe helps you. 
http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/How-to-set-the-vtkMatrix4x4-in-function-SetResliceAxes-of-vtkImageReslice-td5735428.html